# Assembly understanding addressing

Tags: assembly, ida

Could someone help me understanding the adressing? Why is it Ch(12 decimal) different always?

C code

```
   int a = 8;
   int b = 8;
   int c = 8;
   int d = 8;
   int e = 8;
   int f = 8;
   int g = 8;
   int h = 8;
   int i = 8;
```

ASM code

```
mov     [ebp+var_8], 8
mov     [ebp+var_14], 8
mov     [ebp+var_20], 8
mov     [ebp+var_2C], 8
mov     [ebp+var_38], 8
mov     [ebp+var_44], 8
mov     [ebp+var_50], 8
mov     [ebp+var_5C], 8
mov     [ebp+var_68], 8
```

Comment: Placement of parameters within the stack frame is determined by the compiler. These offsets do look a bit odd. What compiler is this?

Comment: You'll have a better chance to get that answered on [RE.SE](http://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Tt is compiled via MSVC2010 x86. Thanks, will check RE webpage, never seen it!

Comment: That's done by the /RTCs option.

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8wtf2dfz.aspx